# SPOOL in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have this table and sample data which I want to spool in a file.
I'm not sure what is the right way to do or the syntax. I tried few ways from internet but couldn't get the right answer.

```
CREATE TABLE RoomType
(
RoomType Varchar2(25),
RoomTypeDesc Varchar2(50)
);

INSERT INTO RoomType VALUES ('STD', 'Standard Room');
INSERT INTO RoomType VALUES ('Business', 'Business Class');
```

Comment: You want to spool those statements to a file (?), or the results of executing them; or you want to query the table and spool *that* output to a file?

Comment: @AlexPoole I want to query the table which I did in oracle and spool the output to a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
SPOOL path/file/to/save/log.log(or txt)
PROMPT ************************************
PROMPT *** CREATION OF OBJECTS          ***
PROMPT ************************************
CREATE TABLE RoomType
(
RoomType Varchar2(25),
RoomTypeDesc Varchar2(50)
);
PROMPT ************************************
PROMPT *** INSERTION                    ***
PROMPT ************************************
INSERT INTO RoomType VALUES (STD, 'Standard Room');
INSERT INTO RoomType VALUES (Business, 'Business Class');
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your commands in a file with your favourite editor( like `vi` ), in your favourite path( let's take `/home/oracle/scripts` ) as a `.sql` file :

```
[oracle@DoonieDB scripts]$ vi RoomTypes.sql
set term[out] off
set feed[back] off
col RoomType format a25
col RoomTypeDesc format a25
spool /home/oracle/scripts/RoomTypes.txt
select * from RoomType;
spool off;
```

*where col setting are used to restrict the length of the columns to keep them in single line.*

Connect to your related schema and call your `.sql` by prefixing with a `@` sign and get `RoomTypes.txt` file with formatted info :

```
[oracle@DoonieDB scripts]$ pwd
/home/oracle/scripts
[oracle@DoonieDB scripts]$ sqlplus hotels/myKey
...    
Connected to:
Oracle Database xxx Enterprise Edition Release 1x.x.x.x.x - 64bit Production
SQL> @RoomTypes.sql
SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database xxx Enterprise Edition Release 1x.x.x.x.x - 64bit Production
[oracle@barbdb12c scripts]$ cat RoomTypes.txt

ROOMTYPE                  ROOMTYPEDESC                                          
------------------------- -------------------------                             
STD                       Standard Room                                         
Business                  Business Class
```